# Is there a way to generate a .mbtiles file from .osm.pbf file

Tags: openstreetmap, vector-tiles, osm.pbf

I have an .osm.pbf file which I want to use to generate vector tiles with (.mbtiles).

Im currently on a windows machine utilising docker, I have tried to use the tool tilemaker (https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker) though I cannot get it to work on my files and get issues like so

"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  Exception during zlib decompression: (-5)
"

I was just wondering if anyone else was able to generate these tiles from said file type, if so could you provide a low level detailed guide on how you did so, as I am new to vector tiles and am getting confused within some circumstances.

For anyone interested I use this code to run the docker:

```
docker run tilemaker tilemaker --input=sud-latest.osm.pbf --output=sud.mbtiles
```

I have to put tilemaker twice as otherwise it says it cannot open the .osm.pbf otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ogr2ogr (see other answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/339130)) to translate osm.pbf into geojson, and then [Mapbox's tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) tool to convert the geojson to mbtiles.

Comment: have you got an installation guide for both of these for windows or docker? as both of the installation materials on the sites are quick confusing or lacking in a low level guide

Comment: I assume that if you have docker, you can easily run linux in a container? I blieve both have instructions for it.

Comment: Ive managed to produce the files I want using both of these, eventually after I figured out how to install both off them, thank you

Comment: Though Ive just noticed that is has produced some odd metadata, its also not compatible with tileserver php, any ideas why this may be? heres a link to an issue on tippecanoe ive made, this way you can see the metadata too https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/issues/898

Answer (score 9):

## Extract `.pbf` to `.mbtiles`

- [**Osmium Tool**](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/)
- [**tippecanoe**](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe)

### Install

```
brew install osmium-tool
brew install tippecanoe
```

### Extract

extract `.pbf` to `.geojson`

```
osmium export xxx.pbf -o xxx.geojson
```

extract `.geojson` to `.mbtiles`

```
tippecanoe -zg -o xxx.mbtiles --drop-densest-as-needed xxx.geojson
```

---

## 2023-08-17 Edit

Using `tilemaker` is a better option

### Install

```bash
git clone https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker.git
cd tilemaker
docker build -t tilemaker .
```

### Extract

```bash
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/srv tilemaker --input=/srv/xxx.osm.pbf --output=/srv/xxx.mbtiles
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a tutorial on how to generate tiles using maptiler:
https://blog.kleunen.nl/blog/tilemaker-generate-map

It is focused on linux, but you can run it on windows as well. You can find a pre-built version of maptiler on the CI:
https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/pull/208/checks?check_run_id=2143761163

Probably soon they will also become available on the github page.
Once you have the prebuilt executable and the resources (config and process lua), you can simply do:

tilemaker.exe --input=sud-latest.osm.pbf --output=sud.mbtiles --process resources/process-openmaptiles.lua --config resources/config-openmaptiles.json

The output works best from zoom level 8 - 14, borders are still missing, so lower zoom levels look pretty empty.

Answer (score 0):

possible solutions  :

1.Might be RAM issue try to run small size osm.pbf file with tilemaker

2.Run tilemaker.exe from executable file (by making build from github tilemaker clone)  ---> it may solve most of issues